# Stripping milliseconds from Extended ISO format

Tags: javascript, date, utc

Javascript's [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) function returns a string in the following format:

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

How can I strip the milliseconds from such a string? That is, I desire a string in this format:

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since ISO date format is fixed width up until the millisecond portion, an alternative to splitting on the '.' is to simply use `substring`, then replace the "Z" timezone designator:

```
var d = new Date()

d.toISOString().substring(0,19)+'Z'

"2015-07-01T21:27:45Z"
```

Comment: I ended up using the [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) javascript library for this. My usage is as follows: `moment.utc().local().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]');`

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date();
var formatted = date.toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z';
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You save it to a variable then do this.

```
//I'm calling the variable date
var startMSindex = date.indexOf(".");
date = date.subString(0, startMSindex) + "Z";
```

Comment: The Z is the timezone designator. Z is a special designator for UTC time, known as "Zulu" time: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/zulu.htm